# 3D Pointcloud Plot

Tags: python, animation, scatter

got some Issues here, I do have Coordinates in lists. These coordinates are from a Laserscanner, which scans in layers, so finished one layer it gets to the next, this is were the indicies and nested lists come from. The single lists for X Y and Z are 720 indices long. And the descriebed earlier nested lists for every indice are representing the layers. This gives me a Structure like shown here:

```
len(X) = 720
X[1] = [ 0. 8.62348279  ... 9.10556606  9.15339632  9.11527918  9.11995584]
```

What did i try until now?

I did try to plot this Stuff as a Scatterplot, which works quite fine.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for i in range(len(X1)):
   plt.scatter(X1[i],Y1[i],Z1[i],marker='x')
plt.show()
```

Now on to my questions:

1. The ScatterPlot, which you see implemented above shows the points in
   a strange "gluLookAt" condition, my first question is how to manipulate
   the Look At Angle or Position. So I´m watching the Plot like I´am in the
   Position of the scanner, or a bit above.
2. How can I plot the single Layers in different colors, there are 24 Layers
   for one scan circle.
3. In addition to show how the scanner works, it would be nice to have an 
   animated scan profile, so every layer get´s scanned one after another.

I hope you guys can help me again, Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: This is not a great question. It is unclear what you are asking. That said, I suspect the answer is to use Pyntcloud - https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud ; this is **much, much** nicer for exploratory 3D plotting than matplotlib.

Comment: Okay I will try, thanks